# Salesforce Communities Login Flow to external APIs

Tags: apex, community, visual-workflow, loginflow

I need to call some external REST APIs each time a user logs into a Salesforce Communities portal. The call should pass over some information about the user from the record in Salesforce.

I've been looking into [Login Flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows) but don't see any clear way to create a custom element or similar to perform this action. Is this possible with a Login Flow or with an APEX trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@invocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) annotation to make a static Apex method available to use in a Login Flow.

You cannot run a trigger on logins as of S17.